# Output FILTER results for each row

Tags: google-sheets

Here I'm trying to count the unique number of times a user upvoted a case:

```js
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B <> "", COUNTIF(CHOOSECOLS(UNIQUE(FILTER({B2:B, D2:D}, D2:D <> "")), 2), J2:J) + 1,))
```

Works fine, but then I try to output the users who upvoted each case:

```js
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(", ", CHOOSECOLS(UNIQUE(FILTER({B2:B, D2:D}, MATCH(D2:D, J2:J, 0))), 1)))
```

This one isn't working. What am I doing wrong? [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12-f7ao_KafXCMDYwDflX50LzjMDwl_1jsbEh-Sgg8vo/edit?usp=sharing)'s a sample sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `ARRAYFORMULA` here because `JOIN` is an aggregate function and `FILTER` by default returns arrays. Use [`MAP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985?hl=en) instead:

```cpp
=MAP(J2:J,LAMBDA(case,IF(case="",,JOIN(", ",UNIQUE(IFNA(FILTER(B2:B,D2:D=case)))))))
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I need to learn MAP... But this is perfect and works exactly like it should, thank you again! <3